# use the struct from a class to construct another class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have two class the first one contains the struct, 
that's what in A.h

```
class A
{
public:
A();
struct structname
{double a;....}；
};
```

and I want to use this struct as an argument of the constructor of B

```
#include "A.h"
B::B(A::structname data)
{
}
```

but I got the error message:
'structname' in 'class A' does not name a type

what is the problem?

details:Two classes are in different .cpp file.
In A.cpp and B.cpp: I just #include the A.h and B.h
In B.h :

```
class A;
class B
{
public:
B(A::structname data);
}
```

actual struct:

```
struct structname
{
std::vector<double> a={0,0,0};
std::vector<double> B={0,0,0};
std::vector<double> c={0,0,0};
std::vector<double> d={0,0,0};
}
```

Comment: I hope that `....` is not in the actual program.

Comment: This is totally possible, see http://ideone.com/aveqY9 the error must be somewhere else. Maybe you messed up your includes?

Comment: @ColinBasnett Could be that CHOCOLEO is experimenting with variadic structures.

Comment: @MtRoad Thanks. I found the problem:
I should #include the A.h before the B.h in the B.cpp
but what my teacher said is the corresponding .h file should always #include first.......

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
{
    public:
    A();
        struct structname
        {
            std::vector<double> a={0,0,0};
            std::vector<double> B={0,0,0};
            std::vector<double> c={0,0,0};
            std::vector<double> d={0,0,0};
        };
};
class B
{
     public:
     B(A::structname data);
};
```

Just format your code. You'll see all your mistakes.

Comment: Yeah I did it too . still cannot run

Comment: Always formate your code. It's very helpful and save you from silly mistakes. If you using C++11 and the headers are fine, there mustn't be error.

Answer (score 0):

Apperently you are forward declaring A in B.h (thats what I read from your snippets). If you are forward declaring A, the compiler only knows that there is somewhere a type named A that is of class type. It does not know about `A::structname` there.

Do your forward declaring the other way round or just avoid nested types at all.